# How to connect a many to many relationship using Prisma

Tags: prisma

I am trying to create and connect a record in a Prisma many to many relationship, but the connection part is not working for me.

Here are my Prisma models:

```
model Ingredient {
  id                Int                 @id @default(autoincrement())
  name              String
  createdAt         DateTime            @default(now())
  calories          Int
  protein           Int
  fat               Int
  carbs             Int
  netCarbs          Int
  metricQuantity    Int
  metricUnit        String
  imperialQuantity  Int
  imperialUnit      String
  recipes           IngredientsOnRecipes[]
  categories        CategoriesOnIngredients[]
  }

  model IngredientCategory {
  id            Int                 @id @default(autoincrement())
  name          String
  ingredients   CategoriesOnIngredients[]
}

model CategoriesOnIngredients {
  ingredient                Ingredient     @relation(fields: [ingredientId], references: [id])
  ingredientId              Int // relation scalar field (used in the `@relation` attribute above)
  ingredientCategory        IngredientCategory @relation(fields: [ingredientCategoryId], references: [id])
  ingredientCategoryId      Int // relation scalar field (used in the `@relation` attribute above)
  assignedAt                DateTime @default(now())

  @@id([ingredientId, ingredientCategoryId])
}
```

Here is the primsa query I am running:

```
   const ingredient = await prisma.ingredient.create({
      data: {
        name: title,
        metricQuantity: parseInt(quantityMetric),
        metricUnit: unitMetric,
        imperialQuantity: parseInt(quantityImperial),
        imperialUnit: unitImperial,
        calories: parseInt(calories),
        netCarbs: parseInt(netCarbs),
        carbs: parseInt(carbs),
        protein: parseInt(protein),
        fat: parseInt(fat),
        categories: {
          ingredientcategory: {
            connect: { id: parseInt(categoryId) },
          },
        },
      },
    });
```

Creating a new ingredient works perfectly, but when I add this section:

```
  categories: {
          ingredientcategory: {
            connect: { id: parseInt(categoryId) },
          },
        },
```

I get the following error:

Unknown arg `ingredientcategory` in data.categories.ingredientcategory for type CategoriesOnIngredientsCreateNestedManyWithoutIngredientInput. Did you mean `createMany`? Available args:
type CategoriesOnIngredientsCreateNestedManyWithoutIngredientInput {
create?: CategoriesOnIngredientsCreateWithoutIngredientInput | List | CategoriesOnIngredientsUncheckedCreateWithoutIngredientInput | List
connectOrCreate?: CategoriesOnIngredientsCreateOrConnectWithoutIngredientInput | List
createMany?: CategoriesOnIngredientsCreateManyIngredientInputEnvelope
connect?: CategoriesOnIngredientsWhereUniqueInput | List
}

Answer (score 1):

You can try executing the following:

```js
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client')
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

const saveData = async () => {
  const ingredient = await prisma.ingredient.create({
    data: {
      name: 'ingredient1',
      categories: {
        create: {
          ingredientCategory: {
            create: {
              name: 'category1',
            },
          }
        }
      },
    },
    select: {
      id: true,
      name: true,
      categories: {
        select: {
          ingredientId: true,
          ingredientCategory: true,
        }
      },
    },
  });

  console.log(JSON.stringify(ingredient, null, 2));
}

saveData()
```

And you will have the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work, I had missed create:{} from my Prisma query.

```
const ingredient = await prisma.ingredient.create({
      data: {
        name: title,
        metricQuantity: parseInt(quantityMetric),
        metricUnit: unitMetric,
        imperialQuantity: parseInt(quantityImperial),
        imperialUnit: unitImperial,
        calories: parseInt(calories),
        netCarbs: parseInt(netCarbs),
        carbs: parseInt(carbs),
        protein: parseInt(protein),
        fat: parseInt(fat),
        categories: {
          create: {
            ingredientCategory: {
              connect: { id: parseInt(categoryId) },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
```